# Looking to fill out most or all of the Fed Ex "Create Label" page using URL query string

Tags: url, query-string, fedex

Looking to create a shipment on [www.fedex.com](http://www.fedex.com)

But fill out most of the fields using a query string at the end of a URL.
Seems like this might not be possible, but need help figuring out how to know whether it is or not.

My "Create Labels" page has a URL ending in -- ?method=doInitialize&utype=null ,
or else sometimes ...
-- ?method=doEntry&link=1&locale=en_US&urlparams=us&sType=F
so it seems promising. Just not sure how to access the names of the required fields (Contact name, Address 1 and 2, etc ) besides guess and check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

--------- **Destination Section Parameters Found**

The query string parameters for the destination contact field are, at the time this answer was written :

```
toData.addressData.contactName         
toData.addressData.addressLine1        
toData.addressData.addressLine2         
toData.addressData.zipPostalCode       
toData.addressData.city                
toData.addressData.stateProvinceCode    
toData.addressData.phoneNumber        
psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].weight
```

Of course, they need to be appended to the original URL using valid [query string syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure) and [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding).

--------- **How Were These Found ?**

These were each found using the page inspector. I found that it is important to cut through the noise by zeroing in on the exact field where the data needs to be entered, and opening up the page inspector to that location.

[image: where to click]

> Right click (Win) or control click (Mac) > "inspect"

This will bring up the following text in the inspector. By trial and error, I discovered that the "name" fields correspond to the working query string parameters.

[image]
The part we are looking for :
[image]

This corresponds to the query string parameter ...

```
toData.addressData.addressLine1
```

... originally listed above.

--------- **Unsolved Parameters**

It's a mystery why this same rule doesn't apply in the same way to other values in the page, like service type (e.g. "Priority Overnight") or package type (e.g. "FedEx Box"). The following, for example, do not fill as expected, even when using the exact same "name" field from the page inspector.

```
psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].carriageValue  
psdData.serviceType                 
psdData.packageType                      
billingData.referenceData.yourReference
```

Maybe it's a URL encoding issue? Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: All of those above-listed "Unsolved Parameters" can be configured to specified values using the "Preferences" section found on the FedEx label creation page. This thread should then, currently, contain enough info to pre-fill all required fields for shipping in the USA such that you can just click "ship", without filling out anything manually.

Comment: Recommend using ...
psdData.mpsRowDataList%5B0%5D.weight
 ... (which utilizes percent–encoding)
instead of  ...
psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].weight      
 ... as the brackets in the former can mess up the hyperlinking in some contexts.